# How to read binary data repeatedly into the same array?

Tags: python, arrays, numeric

What is the right way to repeatedly read fixed amounts of binary from a file into a pre-allocated Python `array`, so that each read overwrites the previous one, and the `array`'s size remains constant?

---

**The goal here is to eliminate the overhead from allocating memory with every read.**

(The application I have in mind is one where performance matters.)

---

For example, this does not work:

```
import struct
import array

# ...

with open(infile, 'rb') as inp:

    unpckr = struct.Struct('<%db' % ncols)
    ary = array.array('b', [0] * ncols)

    for _ in range(nrows):
        ary.fromfile(inp, ncols)
        record = unpckr.unpack_from(ary, 0)

        # ... do stuff with record ...
```

This is because `ary.fromfile` method does not overwrite `ary`; instead, it appends the new data to the end of it.  This means that the `ary`'s size grows with every read, *which defeats the whole idea of fixed-size IO buffer*.

---

Contrast the above with what one can do at the time of *writing* binary data to disk:

```
import struct
import array

# ...

with open(infile, 'r') as inp, open(outfile, 'wb') as out:

    headers = next(inp)
    ncols = len(headers.split(','))
    pckr = struct.Struct('<%db' % ncols)
    ary = array.array('b', [0] * ncols)

    for line in inp:
        data = map(int, line.rstrip('\r\n').split(','))
        pckr.pack_into(ary, 0, *data)
        ary.tofile()

    out.flush()
```

In this second snippet, a small amount of memory is allocated for the `ary` array only once, and is reused over and over.

Comment: One solution is to create a new array before each read.

Comment: numpy also have a efficient fromfile - does that append as well?I cant see this in the documentation

Comment: Use a `bytearray` and [`readinto()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.readinto)